# ¿Es válido o correcto el siguiente Diagrama de Secuencia?

Tags: diseño

tengo el siguiente caso de uso: Iniciar sesión que dice que mientras el usuario quiera intentar iniciar sesión puede ingresar su usuario y contraseña,si el log in es correcto debo de recordar el nickname, mi duda es:

¿si recuerdo el nickname dentro del LOOP estoy recordando todos los nickname con los que pruebe el usuario?

si lo anteriormente dicho es válido entonces ¿debo crear un mensaje del sistema solamente para que me recuerde el nickname cuando la validación es correcta?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: "*¿si recuerdo el nickname dentro del LOOP estoy recordando todos los nickname con los que pruebe el usuario?*" Ni idea, dependerá del código que hayas escrito.

Comment: El primer `opt` sobraría, ¿no? El propio bucle ya comprueba que `autentificacion==false`, luego que el siguiente paso sea volver a comprobar eso suena redundante

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster aún no hay ningún código escrito, esta es la etapa de diseño.

Comment: @eferion es verdad,no me di cuenta de ese detalle,gracias por tu aporte

Comment: @LeoOdriozola No creo que podamos saber lo que hará el código (recordar o no recordar cosas) si no vemos el código.